# Stylesheets not loading after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently working on a language function for my webpage by using mod_rewrite. I can enter an URL with a language option and extract that information in my php index file with $_GET. But for some reason my CSS files wont load any more.

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /books/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(se|en)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$2&language=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My stylesheets are linked like this:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="localhost/books/css/style.css">
```

If I try to find the CSS file in my browser it seems like it's still rewriting even though I got my RewriteCond in place.

Any suggestions as to why this is causing problems?

Comment: Unfortunately makes no difference..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /books/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(se|en)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$2&language=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

because `RewriteCond` just works with the first `RewriteRule` after.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it. Did not know that the `RewriteCond` only worked for the first rule.

Would you mind explaining how `RewriteRule ^ - [L] works`?

Comment: Yes, it's for: in all cases  `RewriteCond` do nothing else after.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for your help @Croises.